# Markerless Augmented Reality for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

I'm using Vuforia for developing AR apps for Android using Unity as a editor. But this uses a target as in images/3D objects etc. But what I want is an app that recognise the environment it is in, like this app [Augment App for Android.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ar.augment&hl=en)

In this app we can place our 3D objects on any terrain and scale or rotate it. I want to build this kind of app but the use case is completely different.

I have tried Kudan, but its a paid SDK.

Comment: Wikitude offers a Unity Plugin that has some markerless functionality. Kudan is free to use, but requires a license in order to upload an app to the Apple or Play Stores. Metaio were doing some interesting work, but Apple snapped them up and hid them away. Nobody else really does any kind of markerless tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markerless tracking is a research field in progress. There are a couple way this is done, but nothing really works well. Even the app you linked uses markers to display models. For this purpose Natural Features (like in Vuforia) are used to distinguish between the environment.

In the screenshots, where it does not use markers it does not use tracking at all. It uses the camera feed and then overlays this with a virtual object, which is previosly uploaded and subtracts the movement of the camera to the location of the object to give the illusion of standing in place.

Comment: thanks for the reply , coming to the second part of your answer is there any tutorials or steps to do so ?? so i can pick it up from scratch?? I only know to build small android apps and small games in unity.

Comment: What you describe as an "illusion" is tracking. Marker tracking works in much the same way, it is simply using the marker as a reference point. The only different between that and markerless tracking is that markerless uses an arbitrary reference point in the scene rather than a predetermined point provided by another object in that scene. Marker tracking is far more robust, it has to be said, and for the most part I daresay that the majority of AR that people use in their day to day lives will work by using markers.